# Set of $n \times n$ complex matrices with trace $c$ and rank $1$, which are closed, which closures are smooth submanifolds?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This is a follow-up to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426068/single-textgl-n-mathbbc-conjugacy-class-dimension-as-algebraic-variety).

For each $c \in \mathbb{C}$, define the set$$\Sigma_c := \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) : \text{Tr}(A) = c,\text{ Rank}(A) = 1\}.$$Again, I have two questions.

1. For which $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is the set $\Sigma_c$ closed?
2. For which $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is the closure $\overline{\Sigma_c}$ of $\Sigma_c$ a smooth submanifold of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: The closure of the set of matrices of rank $1$ is just the union of this set and $\{0\}$. (More generally, the closure of $\{A \in M_n(\mathbb C)\,|\,\mathrm{rk} A = r\}$ is $\{A \in M_n(\mathbb C)\,|\,\mathrm{rk} A \leq r\}$.

This directly implies that $\Sigma_c$ is closed if and only if $0$ does not belong to $\overline \Sigma_c$, which is the case if and only if $c \neq 0$

Comment: Isn't the trace a continuous function with respect to any decent topology on the matrices? If so, the inverse image of a singleton is closed provided $c\neq 0$, no?

Comment: @uniquesolution $tr^{-1}(c)$ is closed in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, but $\Sigma_c$ is the intersection of this set with the set of rank 1 matrices (which is not closed).

Comment: Someone kindly pointed out the error in my previous Comment, but has deleted it.  I said that $\Sigma_0$ is empty, but e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has trace $0$ and rank $1$.  Any such matrix $A$ would be similar to this block, padded with the necessary extra zeros on the diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1., PseudoNeo can transform his comment into an answer.

For 2.

If $c=0$, then $\overline{\Sigma_c}$ is a cone and $0_n$ is a singular point; it is not a smooth manifold.

If $c\not= 0$, then $\overline{\Sigma_c}=\Sigma_c$. We may assume that $c=1$. $D_k=\{U;rank(U)=k\}$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $r(2n-r)$. Since $\Delta=\{U;rank(U)=1,tr(U)\not= 0\}$ is open in $D_1$, it is a manifold of dimension $2n-1$ and, moreover, a punctured cone. Considering $f:U\in \Delta\rightarrow U/tr(U)\in \Sigma_1$, we deduce that $\Sigma_1$ is a manifold of dimension $2n-2$.